# Coin Flipping - Probability and Value Proposition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Rusty with probability here...

> The question is: 
>   Flip a coin 11 times.  If you get 8 tails or less, I will pay you \$1.
>   Otherwise, you pay me \$7.
>
> Step 1. Find the expected value of the proposition.  Round your answer to two decimal places.
>
> Step 2. If you played this game 615 times how much would you expect to win or lose? (Losses must be entered as negative.)

I think that the expected value of the proposition is the sum of the probability of getting 8 tails or less times times the 1 dollar value, plus probability of getting more thand 8 tails  times the $7 value.

I would like a walkthrough of the mindset and reasoning, not just the answer so I can learn how to approach the problem. I am also learning how to solve with R.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Hint: $E(X)=np$

Comment: Key fact: If X is the number of tails in 11 tosses of a fair coin, then $P(X \le 8) = 0.9673$ computed in R as `pbinom(8, 11, .5).`

Comment: If you round the answer to two places in #1 as ordered, then it seems to me that your answer to #2 is off by several whole dollars.

Comment: Mark even though we'd like to do your HW for you we're not supposed to.  Can you see a problem if there was a website where students could just post their HW and others just do them for them?  The rules are you show us exactly where you got stuck and we try to help you get past it.

Comment: Clement and Gregory, I will add where I got stuck. Looking to learn, not just get the answer. One reason is I am learning to evaluate these problems with R.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^{11}$ possible outcomes, of these there are $\binom{11}{9}+\binom{11}{10}+\binom{11}{11}=67$ outcomes in which I pay you $7$ dollars.

Therefore the expected cash the other player gets is:

$\frac{2^{11}-67}{2^{11}}-7\frac{67}{2^{11}}=\frac{1512}{2^{11}}\approx0.73$.

So I don't recommend you play the game.

---

The expected cash after playing the game $n$ times is $0.73\times n$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of tails in $11$ tosses of a fair coin. We have

$$P(X > 8) = \sum_{k=9}^{11} \binom{11}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{2^{11-k}}$$

This can be derived by noting that for this distribution, we have 11 spots to place a metaphorical heads or a tails. Each spot has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of being a heads or a tails, and we have $11$ choose $k$ ways of rearranging these spots around.

Let $Y$ be the random variable representing the amount of money we make from playing the game once. We have

$$E(Y) = (1)(1 - P(X>8)) - 7P(X>8)$$
$$E(Y) = 1 - 8\sum_{k=9}^{11} \binom{11}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{2^{11-k}}$$

$$E(Y) = \frac{189}{256}$$

Playing this game 615 times we expect to have made

$$615 * \frac{189}{256} = \frac{116235}{256}$$

To reiterate in decimals, we expect to make roughly $74$ cents each time we play the game and if we play it 615 times, we expect to make roughly $ \$ 454.04$ .

**Note: I have answered this taking the perspective that the "you" in the question is the "we" in my answer**